# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 90-96: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
url= 'https://yandex.ru/search/xml?user=uid-2h3232xfhboy&key=03.292922330523:6b4c80ghghghhghgdsfdsfds4c4b4a7872fb7d2bb04bfdgbb02b76c3d&query='
key = "абс"
 url = url + key
        print(url)
        xml = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

But I got an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 90-96: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What do I do?

I tried to do `url= url.encode("utf-8")`
But didn't help. Got this error:

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'

I tried to do this:
`url = u''.join((self.ya_url, key)).encode('utf-8')`
As suggested here: [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20?rq=1)

But got the same error

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'timeout'

What do I do?

Comment: Have you gone through some of the other Q&As that are very similar to this? (See the "Related" sidebar.)

Comment: @glibdud  yes, I have gone through some Q&As that are very similar to this(see last 3 paragraphs of question)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049151/attributeerror-bytes-object-has-no-attribute-timeout) for an explanation of the `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use non-ASCII characters in a URL. You need to quote your `key` value appropriately:

```
import urllib.parse

url= 'https://yandex.ru/search/xml?user=uid-2h3232xfhboy&key=03.292922330523:6b4c80ghghghhghgdsfdsfds4c4b4a7872fb7d2bb04bfdgbb02b76c3d&query='
key = "абс"
quoted = urllib.parse.quote(key)
url = url + quoted
```

Answer (score 0):

This method work for me (i use Pycharm ide) .   you go to client.py , then change the request.encode('ascii')   to request.encode('utf-8) or any encoder you want . Now it should be work with no problem

Edit: you need to change the source file in order to use utf character in url  . in request.encode , it has been hard code to ascii